# Getting estimated kindle sales from mws

Tags: amazon-mws

I’m interested in getting estimated sales of kindle books from the mws api.

This is for all kindle books in a specific category.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this information directly from Amazon. What you can do however, is make your own assessment. The best way to do this is getting the products competitive pricing to estimate how much you would be selling the item for as well as sales ranking for that item. 
Use products API: [Here](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetCompetitivePricingForSKU.html)

Remember:
The Amazon Sales Rank is a number which captures the item's popularity in a certain category, sales rank exists for all products who are part of a category (some products don't have a category). The Sales Rank interval can be between 1 and 1 million+.

In short, the sale rank in amazon (updated hourly) is the factor of how product is selling in comparison with others in same category the lower rank , the better a product is selling, Rank #1 is the best. you can sell it very fast in 24hr if your price is relatively competitive
Unfortunately, Amazon doesn’t reveal the algorithm of its sale ranking.

You can get a general idea of the sales ranking [here](https://garlicpressseller.com/fba-sales/amazon-sales-rank-chart-2019-fba/).